# How to remove the contour of nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

[image]

I am using networkx in python to draw a network for emojis. Here is my code:

```
G = nx.Graph()
# emoji_sim is a nested list contains cosine similarity of each emojis pair.
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(emoji_sim))

labels=dict(zip(range(len(G.nodes())),emoji_dict.values()))

nx.draw(G, edge_color='white', node_color='none', with_labels=True, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

My question is, is there anyway to remove the contour of the node? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `node_shape` attribute, which is specified like a matplotlib marker (see http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html).

You can just specify `None` for the attribute:

```
nx.draw(G, edge_color='white', node_color='none', with_labels=True, labels=labels, node_shape=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: How to use some color for edge node but with `nx.draw_networkx_nodes ` command, instead of `nx.draw`?